# reverse proxy using sails 1, nginx, and node is very version dependent, how to fix?

Tags: node.js, nginx, apache2, sails.js

I would like to have a more stable deployment of a sails 1 app on an AWS ubuntu server using nginx as reverse proxy.

**Goal:**

To have a non-version-dependent deployment of our app.

**In particular:**

We have an app on an AWS server.

App details include:

- mobile focused
- websockets enabled
- reverse proxy with nginx
- app persisting with pm2

Deployment details include

- AWS  ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- mysql 8.x database
- sails 1.2.4
- nginx 1.14.0
- node 8.4.0

**The issue:**

I was only able to get the reverse proxy working with the above versions of sails, nginx, and node.  Any other combination resulted in a 403 error from the app server.  Postman GET requests to the server when the app is served directly  return a "sails.sid" cookie. However, when the app is served through any other  reverse proxy software combination, no "sails.sid" cookie comes back in the GET header. I got the same no cookie GET request with apache2 reverse proxy.

When I hit the app directly (not through the reverse proxy) the cookies returned fine.

**What I have tried**

- different versions of node, sails1, nginx, apache2
- node versions > 10.22.0 cause the error

there is a known deprecation in node > 10.22.0 of the command

[link to node deprecation](https://nodejs.org/api/deprecations.html#deprecations_dep0066_outgoingmessage_prototype_headers_outgoingmessage_prototype_headernames)

```
The http module OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers and OutgoingMessage.prototype._headerNames properties are deprecated.
```

This seems to break the nginx reverse proxy handling of headers from the sails app.

I have not seen a fix in nginx,  and in particular nginx version 1.16.0 will break the headers.

**other things I have tried**

- ownership and permissions (chmod, chown) are ok
- apache2 reverse proxy: same problem as with nginx 1.16.0: no headers. I.E. the reverse proxy works, but the app returns a 403 code through the apache2 reverse proxy.
- various permutations of versioning: sails, nginx, node

**things I might try**

Somewehere in the node-modules of sails, there may lurk header code depending on this old syntax.  This could possibly be patched with a replace new-for-old on the appropriate statements. Just a thought.

**What I would like:**

Show me how to get this app working, i.e. get all the headers back from a vanilla Postman  GET request, in  a way that does not depend on these specific versions of sails, nginx, and node.

If I am missing something glaringly obvious, even better.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a similar setup with node 11.15.0 and it works.

What is your nginx configuration?

Comment: Currently using the server block config with straight HTTP, only one backend server.  I can upload the backendServer.conf file in sites-available if you like

Comment: it could be useful for checking it.

Comment: Here is the code in the  /etc/nginx/sites-available folder. Remember that you have to symlink it over to the sites-enabled folder.

Comment: first half : 
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name yourDomain.com ;

    location / {
        proxy_pass    "http://127.0.0.1:1337";

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header Port $server_port;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_pass_request_headers on;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        }

Comment: second half:  
    location /socket.io/ {
      proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:1337/socket.io/";

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header Port $server_port;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_pass_request_headers on;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        }
}

Answer (score 0):

Here is the server block code I tried to put in the comments. Remeber that you have to symlink it to the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled folder as well. This works for straight HTTP requests.  Note that your app will only see the client "127.0.0.1". If you want to get the IP addresses from your clients out in the wild, you need to get them from the nginx reverse proxy server itself.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name yourDomain.com ;

    location / {
        proxy_pass    "http://127.0.0.1:1337";

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header Port $server_port;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_pass_request_headers on;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        }

    location /socket.io/ {
      proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:1337/socket.io/";

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header Port $server_port;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_pass_request_headers on;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        }
}
```

Comment: Well, try, for the location /, with:

Define upstream as:

```
upstream app_nodes {
    server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1337;
    keepalive 64;
}
```

And add these after proxy_pass:

```
    proxy_pass http://app_nodes;
    proxy_pass_header  Set-Cookie;
    proxy_pass_header X-XSRF-TOKEN;
    proxy_read_timeout 240s;
```